# Sorting of permutations

Tags: filtering, combinatorics, permutation

I would like to output the list of possible permutations of 4 indices but sorted in a certain way. I know that I can the list of possible permutations with

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, d}]
```

which outputs

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, d, c}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {a, d, b, c}, 
>  {a, d, c, b}, {b, a, c, d}, {b, a, d, c}, {b, c, a, d}, {b, c, d, a}, 
>  {b, d, a, c}, {b, d, c, a}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, b, a, d}, 
>  {c, b, d, a}, {c, d, a, b}, {c, d, b, a}, {d, a, b, c}, {d, a, c, b}, 
>  {d, b, a, c}, {d, b, c, a}, {d, c, a, b}, {d, c, b, a}}
> ```

Now I would like to sort out the "cyclic" terms, i.e., `a, b, c, d`, `d, a, b, c`, `c, d, a, b`, etc. from the "non-cyclic" terms i.e. `a, b, d, c`, etc.

What do I have to add to the code, please?

Comment: So you want a separate list of cyclic permutations from the noncyclic ones? You can easily generate the cyclic ones with `NestList[]` + `RotateLeft[]`, and then follow up with `Complement[]` to get the rest.

Comment: I have tried 

`NestList[RotateRight, {a, b, c, d}, 3]`

then used 

 `Complement[Permutations[{a, b, c, d}], 
 NestList[RotateRight, {a, b, c, d}, 3]]`

Comment: You could maybe put that as an answer to your question, since you figured it pretty quickly. ;)

Comment: If you wanted to `Select` from the original list of permutations you could use `Select[Permutations[{a, b, c, d}], With[{perm = #}, NestWhile[RotateLeft, perm, First[#] =!= a &]] == {a, b, c, d} &]` to get the cyclic permutations (and then use the complement to get the others, if needed).

Comment: You could do something like `cyclicQ[a_,cycle_]:=SequenceCount[Join@@{a,a},cycle]!=0;` then use it with `GatherBy[Permutations[{a,b,c,d}],cyclicQ[#,{a,b,c,d}]&]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried

`NestList[RotateRight, {a, b, c, d}, 3]`

then used

`Complement[Permutations[{a, b, c, d}], NestList[RotateRight, {a, b, c, d}, 3]]`